# Evaluating $\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4t}}e^{-y^2}dy$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fubini-tonelli-theorems, completing-the-square

I wish to find the function $u(x,t)$ which solves the following PDE:

$$\begin{cases}
\partial_{t}u - \Delta u = 0, \; t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}, \; x \in \mathbb{R}^{d} \\
u(0,x) = e^{-x^{2}}, \; x\in \mathbb{R}^{d}
\end{cases}$$

After several steps related to applying the Fourier transform I arrive at
$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4t}}e^{-y^2}dy$$
To evaluate this integral, I know I must

1. Complete the square
2. Apply Fubini's theorem
3. Note that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt{\pi}$

However, after several attempts at doing this I cannot arrive at a function $u$ which satisfies the PDE. My latest attempt yielded: $$u = \frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{4t}}}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}} e^{\frac{(4t+1)x^2}{4^3 t^3}} \Bigg(\frac{\pi \cdot 4t}{4t+1}\Bigg)^{\frac{d}{2}}$$ which, upon inspecting the boundary condition, results in dividing by zero since $t = 0$ is in the denominator of many terms.

Is my computation of the integral correct? If so, that will mean my error lies elsewhere in my work.

---

Newest attempt:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\prod_{j=1}^{d}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{(x_j-y_j)^2}{4t}}e^{-y_j^2}dy_j &= \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\prod_{j=1}^{d}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x_j^2 +2x_j y_j -y_j^2}{4t}}e^{-y_j^2}dy_j \\
&= \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\prod_{j=1}^{d}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{2x_j y_j -y_j^2}{4t}}e^{-y_j^2}dy_j \\
&=\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\prod_{j=1}^{d}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(\frac{1}{4t}+1)y_j^2 + \frac{x_j y_j}{2t}}dy_j
\end{align*}

Now complete the square of: $-(\frac{1}{4t}+1)y_j^2 + \frac{x_j y_j}{2t}$.

1. Factor out the coefficient of the squared term: $-(\frac{1}{4t}+1)\left ( y_j^2 - \frac{x_jy_j}{2t\cdot (\frac{1}{4t}+1)}\right )$
2. \begin{align*}y_j^2 - \frac{x_jy_j}{2t\cdot (\frac{1}{4t}+1)}&= (y_j -\frac{\frac{x_j}{2t\cdot (\frac{1}{4t}+1)}}{2})^2 - \frac{x_j^2}{t^2(\frac{1}{4t}+1)^{2}}\end{align*}
3. $-(\frac{1}{4t}+1)\left( (y_j -\frac{\frac{x_j}{2t\cdot (\frac{1}{4t}+1)}}{2})^2 - \frac{x_j^2}{t^2(\frac{1}{4t}+1)^{2}} \right) =\\\boxed{ -(\frac{1}{4t}+1)\left (y_j -\frac{x_j}{t\cdot (\frac{1}{4t}+1)} \right)^2 + \frac{x_j^2}{t^2(\frac{1}{4t}+1)}}$

Now substitute the above into the integrand and manipulate to obtain the gaussian integral.

\begin{align*}
\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\prod_{j=1}^{d}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(\frac{1}{4t}+1)y_j^2 + \frac{x_j y_j}{2t}}dy_j &= \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\prod_{j=1}^{d}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ -(\frac{1}{4t}+1)\left (y_j -\frac{x_j}{t\cdot (\frac{1}{4t}+1)} \right)^2 + \frac{x_j^2}{t^2(\frac{1}{4t}+1)}}dy_j\\
&= \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\cdot e^{\frac{x^2}{t^2(\frac{1}{4t}+1)}}\prod_{j=1}^{d}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ -(\frac{1}{4t}+1)\left (y_j -\frac{x_j}{t\cdot (\frac{1}{4t}+1)} \right)^2}dy_j
\end{align*}
Let $z = \sqrt{(\frac{1}{4t}+1)}\left (y_j -\frac{x_j}{t\cdot (\frac{1}{4t}+1)} \right) \implies dz = \left (\sqrt{(\frac{1}{4t}+1)} \right ) dy_j $
\begin{align*}
&= \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\cdot e^{\frac{x^2}{t^2(\frac{1}{4t}+1)}}\prod_{j=1}^{d}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\frac{1}{4t}+1)}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ -z^2}dz \\
&= \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\cdot e^{\frac{x^2}{t^2(\frac{1}{4t}+1)}}\prod_{j=1}^{d}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\frac{1}{4t}+1)}}\sqrt{\pi}\\
&= \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\cdot e^{\frac{x^2}{t^2(\frac{1}{4t}+1)}} \cdot \left (\frac{\pi}{(\frac{1}{4t}+1)} \right)^{\frac{d}{2}}\\ 
&=\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\cdot e^{\frac{x^2}{t^2(\frac{1}{4t}+1)}} \cdot \left (\frac{4\pi t}{4t+1} \right)^{\frac{d}{2}} \\
&=\boxed{ e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}\cdot e^{\frac{x^2}{t^2(\frac{1}{4t}+1)}} \cdot \left (\frac{1}{4t+1} \right)^{\frac{d}{2}}}
\end{align*}

But again, this seems to be incorrect.

---

**solved:** $$u(x,t) = \boxed{\left (\frac{1}{4t+1} \right)^{\frac{d}{2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t+1}}}$$

Everyone take my experience as a caution to check your arithmetic!

Comment: Yes you don't get $e^{-x^2}$ as $t\to 0^+$ so it cannot be correct. Your solution looks very close to being correct though (it should be on the form $a(t) e^{-b(t)x^2}$ and one way to find the solution is to use this as an ansatz in the PDE and solve for $a,b$). You can simplify your solution by removing the $4\pi$ factors which cancel so it looks like you got the prefactor $a(t)$ term correct - but if I'm not mistaken the exponential should be $e^{-x^2/(4t+1)}$ so my bet it that your mistake is in the completion of the square. Writing up how you did this would be a useful thing to add.

Comment: @Winther I've updated my post with my full attempt written up.

Comment: One mistake in 2: $(1/2)/2= 1/4$ and not 1. The squared x term is wrong. This will modify the last result to $t^2$ replaced by $16t^2$ in the exponential. Combine the two exponential into one and you will have the answer.

Comment: You can also use again Fourier transform, it might result in less errors. Your first integral is indeed a convolution of Gaussian functions, so its Fourier transform is a product of Gaussian functions ...

Comment: @Winther Ah, arithmetic my weakest link! You may add your comment as an Answer and i'll accept it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the integral right is just be being really careful in all steps. To be sure you have the correct answer you should first check that you get the correct limit as $t\to 0^+$ and if so the best test is to insert it into the PDE and verify that it satisfy it.

There are also other ways you can find the solution to check it. For example from completing the square its easy to see that the solution should be on the form $u(x,t) = a(t)e^{-b(t)x^2}$ where $a(0) = b(0) = 1$ to match the initial condition. Using this as an ansatz the PDE gives us
$$(\dot{a} - a\dot{b}x^2)e^{-b(t)x^2} = \sum_i (-2ab + 4ab^2 x_i^2)e^{-b(t)x^2} = (-2abd + 4ab^2 x^2)e^{-b(t)x^2}$$
which gives you the simple ODEs $\dot{b} = -4b^2$ and $\frac{\dot{a}}{a} = -2db$. Solving for $b$ gives $b = \frac{1}{4t+1}$. Then solving for $a$ gives $a = (1+4t)^{-d/2}$ so the solution is $u =  (1+4t)^{-d/2}e^{-x^2/(1-4t)}$ which agrees with what you found.

Another way would be to take the Fourier transform of the PDE to find
$$\dot{\hat{u}} + k^2\hat{u} = 0\to \hat{u}(k,t) = \hat{u}(k,0)e^{-k^2t}$$ and then take the Fourier transform of the initial condition and finally the inverse transform of $\hat{u}(k,t)$. However in this case this is not any simpler as you will have to evaluate the (complex) Fourier integrals (unless you have some transform tables you can look up the answer from).